# What is the best way to position a 'frame' around something in html?

Tags: html, css, position

I do not mean an html <frame>. I mean something like the frame that goes around this text box that I am typing into on here, with a border and a button bar with some icons in it.

I'd like some editable content that can exist in 2 modes. The first is view mode, where you see the content. The second is editing mode, where a frame appears around it with any controls needed to assist with the editing.

I'd like the frame to not interrupt the normal page flow of the content. So if there was something very close above the content, then the tool bar would sit on top of it in the z-plane. The frame should appear to sit on top of the page, not within it.

I thought about getting the absolute screen coordinates of the thing being wrapped and using 'fixed' positioning to get the frame in the right place.

But I am wondering if 'absolute' positioning might work? Except in this case the absolutely positioned frame would be the parent of the thing it wraps, and 'absolute' positions a child relative to a parent, not a parent relative to a child. Or could a child that is positioned with absolute actually have a larger size than the child, and therefore wrap it like I describe?

Answer (score 0):

You simply need a parent div that contains a div for the header bar and a second div for both input and output.

You would then hide the input and populate the output div with the contents of the input whenever your user was 'done' (simulated here by clicking 'Submit').

I've created a fiddle demonstrating this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/johsqt6y/2/).

Note that the input field would need a `calc()` applied to it in order to adjust for its width.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for creating a fiddle for it, much appreciated. It difers from what I want, in that the header part does not sit on top of the page outwith the normal page flow, that is, with z-index > 1. But the idea of structuring everything within a parent div and using show/hide is a most helpful suggestion.